# How to style @react-native-picker/picker picker text?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to style the picker but it doesn't take fontFamily, padding or fontSize. Is there any way to aplply those styles to this text?

I 've attempted using style and itemStyle, but those properties have no effect.

(Tested on Android phone)

```
<View style={{borderRadius: 20, overflow: 'hidden', marginVertical: 5}}>
  <Picker
    style={[styles.input, {marginVertical: 0}]}
    selectedValue={selectedLanguage}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
      setSelectedLanguage(itemValue)
    }>
    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
  </Picker>
</View>
```

styles.input

```
input: {
    backgroundColor: colors.pink,
    color: 'white',
    width: windowWidth * 0.8,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    marginVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 20,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Light', 
  },
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Move fontSize, fontFamily, ... to `itemStyle` and remove it from `styles.input`, be like:

```
<View style={{borderRadius: 20, overflow: 'hidden', marginVertical: 5}}>
  <Picker
    style={[styles.input, {marginVertical: 0}]}
    selectedValue={selectedLanguage}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
      setSelectedLanguage(itemValue)
    }
    itemStyle={{
      fontSize: 20,
      fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Light',
    }}>
    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
  </Picker>
</View>
```

styles.input:

```
input: {
  backgroundColor: colors.pink,
  color: 'white',
  width: windowWidth * 0.8,
  paddingVertical: 10,
  paddingHorizontal: 20,
  marginVertical: 5,
  borderRadius: 20,
},
```

More information: https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker#itemstyle

Comment: I tried using itemStyle but it had no effect.

Comment: @AndrésValenzuelaOrmeño I read that library issues. `itemStyle`, `fontFamily`(Item props) not work both Android and iOS. You need change library.